# ABP.IO v4 generate proxy Error: [Invalid Module] Backend module "app" does not exist in API definition

Tags: asp.net-core, abp

Just created a fresh Abp v4.0.0 project.
Everything works fine, DB created, swagger shows the endpoints, admin user logged in; and upon generating the proxies:

```
abp generate-proxy
```

I got the error:

```
[Invalid Module] Backend module "app" does not exist in API definition.
```

My environment:

```
Node: v14.15.1
NPM: v6.14.9
Angular CLI: 11.0.3
OS: win32 x64
@abp/ng.schematics: ~4.0.0
```

Comment: I recommend checking [here](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/5725)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that everything provided by `Abp` has it's own module and doesn't need JS proxies. You **only** need to generate-proxy when you create your custom endpoints (An endpoint is an application service like `CrudAppService` or anything that inherits from `IApplicationService`.

[image: app module]